Bintray in Flutter project in 2024
I have an issue with a Bintray repository. I started collaborating on a Flutter project today, October 11, 2024, meaning I began my collaboration today. This project began in 2019 and used dependencies from repositories like Bintray. However, this repository shut down in June 2021. As a result, it’s practically impossible to download dependencies from that site. If you try to access that URL, you get a 403 error when attempting to fetch those dependencies. As I mentioned, I'm collaborating on this project and trying to debug it, but this error occurs. What can I do?
Here is my build.gradle
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

this is pubspec.yaml:
name: ciprrd_service
description: OLE (Observaciones Litorales del Ecuador).

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+3


environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  sqflite: ^1.1.8
  path: ^1.7.0
  intl: ^0.16.1
  bubble_tab_indicator: "^0.1.4"
  fluttertoast: ^7.1.8
  mapbox_gl: "^0.11.0"
  sliding_up_panel: "^1.0.1"
  dio: ^3.0.10
  location: ^3.2.4
  path_provider: ^1.6.27
  url_launcher: ^5.4.2
  
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+4
  provider: ^4.3.3
  sleek_circular_slider: ^1.2.0
  flutter_secure_storage: ^3.3.5
  expansion_card: ^0.1.0

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  
  
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
  imgur: ^1.1.1
  pdf: ^2.1.0
  open_file: ^3.2.1
  permission_handler: ^5.1.0+2
  json_annotation: ^3.1.1
  


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/app/
    - assets/map_styles/
    - assets/markers/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: MyFlutterApp
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/MyFlutterApp.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages

how you can see, I put mavenCentral in the repositories section, but nothing happens
I changed to maven repository from Jcenter, bit it still showing me the error
